# HVAC wiring help!

Tags: hvac

my HVAC system is blowing hot air. Thermostat says its cooling but cold air is blowing out of the outside unit and hot air inside the house. A friend suggested connecting the orange wire from the unit to the yellow wire from the unit and the T wire. It for now solved the issue but this fix is only temporary. Does anyone know what causes this and how to fix it properly. I have notice a noise from my outside unit when it turns off now that was not there before. Best way to describe noise is it sounds like air brakes being released just not as loud. I changed the thermostat inside thinking that was it but it did not work. Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Unless you changed the wires before to cause the problem, switching wires usually not a good idea.  The problem seems to be more mechanical.

Comment: Did you change anything when it stopped working? If you set it to heating, does it cool instead?

Comment: Is the HVAC system "dual mode" meaning it can function both as an air conditioner and a heat pump??

Comment: The wire colors are not standard.  What was the original connection and what did you change.  Specify the connection LETTERS not the colors.

Comment: Ok ac was running. Went  to turn it from cool to off but accidently switched the heat on. heat ran maybe 2 minutes at the most when I realized what I did i turned it off.  It stayed off for 2 hours went to leave put thermostat on cool set temp to 74. Returned home 5 hours later and that is when I noticed what I stated earlier. Returned home to heat on but thermostat says its cooling

Comment: As far as what wires I changed, it was all where the  thermostat wire connects to the outside unit nothing at the thermostat on the wall was changed. The wires where orange to orange and yellow to yellow and so on. disconnected the orange wire from my unit and attached it to the 2 yellow wires.  1 yellow wire from my unit and 1 yellow wire from the T wire

Answer (score 2):

If you have Nest or similar thermostat, it will use the O/B wire to switch the outdoor unit from cooling to heating.

It is reversing valve in your heat pump systems outdoor unit.

That valve in the outside unit is supposed to revert the flow of coolant, from cold to heat.

That valve sometimes gets stuck or simply stops working.

It looks like this, but yours might look different depending on the AC model.

[image: reverse]

In most cases it is the activator that is not working.

You might be lucky to find replacement for the solenoid, and do not have to replace the whole valve.

Comment: thanks to all for the help